# How can I create Ethereum wallet addresses that can be revoked after certain time? Is it possible to do that?

Tags: solidity, dapps

How can I create Ethereum wallet addresses that can be revoked after certain time? Is it possible to do that? I am trying to create temporary wallets for employees in a company for their company expenses, so that the accounts can be revoked later according to certain conditions or time period.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly straightforward use case. You can hold the Ethers or Tokens in a smart contract account. Add a spending function that can be called only by authorized employees and a revoke function that can sent the balance remaining to the owner.